# Diary app with revision history for notes and note migration

Tags: android, productivity, planning, android-app, diary

I am looking for an agenda app for Android with the following features:

Each day, you can add and modify a sequence of notes, which can be added by clicking on the plus button, selecting the in-between note space where the note is to be inserted (if, there are already other notes, and the click location before insertion button is toggled on, else just add the note at the end of the list), and, then, from the list page, you are taken to the child screen B where you can edit all the details pertaining to the note. When the note is finished, you can click save, and you are taken back to the parent screen A (with all the notes for the day).

On screen A, you may also click the the top, on a rearrange notes entry from the three dots menu, which allows you to drag all the entries and rearrange them, then you can click on the save button, to save the every layout again.

Each note, when displayed, is not editable. This, caters towards the difficulty to delete edit or insert unwanted text, destroying the diary and making it useless (for instance when it is in your pocket and you forgot to close it or when your child edits it or when you just make a mistake, you don't notice it, and when you go back in time and check your text you just realize the text is not there).

To avoid this situation, each every is not editable and has a pencil icon to the right next to it.

When you click on the pencil icon next to an entry on page A, you are taken to page B for that note.

On page B, you can see all the revision history, for that note, ad a list. For instance, after a note is added, if it is edited, the text for the note is copied below, and the time stamp of the previous note appears below, for when the note was added (smaller green text, in the upper right hand corner), as well as the current time for the note at the top of the list, for when this note is added (with the text of the note below copied and selected). The user can then enter the need new note, and save it.

Clicking on a note on screen A, takes you to the note revision history for that note on screen B.

Each note, also, has attached to the note (below), a special note section (this double note, can be blank, for stuff we plan, but when the plan comes from someone else for instance teacher homework or doctor or psychologist, we specify the person and the location that made the change to the appointment time or place and where the scheduling change took place, for instance, phone call, school classroom, or psychologist office).

In fact, below the entry, there is also a reschedule button, that allows the user to migrate the whole history to a different day.

The person that makes the change may not have access to your app and may just be a name (unlike on Google Calendar).

In each case, when you search notes, you may also opt to search revision history, including the who were, field, by clicking on the appropriate "deepen search" button.

When the user migrates the history, they are taken to page A for the different day where the entry with the given history goes, and allowed to select, where within the entries, they want to notes inserted. Then they click on the migrate button that appears to insert the entry there. They may then click on the entry to be taken back to page B for that entry (and, make further edits there, if desired). Again, even for rescheduling, there is a special note note, indicating, (if the person rescheduling is not yourself), the person and place where this rescheduling, physically happened. Again, the person may not be in your contacts, you enter manually the name, same goes for the place where the rescheduling happened, but you can then search them through advanced search.

Why do we need revision history? How many times, is there a rescheduling, and then confusion arises, because, at the meeting,  there is a different doctor or psychologist or teacher they shows up, and they ask, why the time is different. What happened? Who changed the appointment time or details? What happened? By viewing the revision history, you can see that. And, you can answer the question (properly, and appropriately).

You can also see for yourself, what happened, when your wish to review this. You don't just delete text and replace this, and never again see what was there before (in this app).

You can also cancel entries, in which case deletion history can be viewed by simply clicking on the canceled entries menu entry from the three dots menu. You can reschedule a cancelled entry, if you wish. You can view migration history. You can view notes that were migrated, from the three dots menu. This way, is someone gets back to you, and asks you if something was scheduled for a given date, but there is nothing there, they can check if something was actually migrated (or you can check for yourself that that happened).

It would also be nice if the whole calendar were stored in Google Drive.

Thanks.

Hi, I deleted the project-managenent and time-management tags and added Android and Android app tags, I could not have included all the tags although all were appropriate because a maximum of five is allowed.

Comment: I suggest self hosting gitlab.

Comment: Hi. As there are many Note apps out there, please state the ones you have already tried out and how they don't meet your requirements.

Comment: I have tired Business Calendar, To Do List, Calendar Planner, Goldie, and even Setmore, and others. None of them have history for events (I can't see who made changes to an event's time or where an event was migrated from, as described here). None of the given apps do what I describe. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder whether anyone can take on this project as I am currently disabled and do not have the finances. Nevertheless, such an app would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I would be very happy if someone wrote an app that implemented this functionality.

Comment: @achainsan I am looking for an Android app

Comment: Hello, I would like to add a note to why this app would be very useful, especially to young kids and disabled users that needed support, for their tasks, and their doings, in their life.

Comment: When a task or appointment is rescheduled, the disabled user needs to keep track of that. However, they cannot cancel the appointment scheduling revision history, because they may be held accountable by a parent or another staff member, friend, person, or what not, with what happened with the appointment rescheduling. They may then not remember, and need to consult the app for this. The app, would provide reliability and support, for this information.